# How to do a "X-axis" or more visualization?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, visualization

I have a pandas dataframe in python3 which contains attributes. One of these attributes is an integer between 1 and 54. I would like to plot this against some of the attributes, but I would need to visualize each column as the value or more. So 1+,2+,3+,...,n+ on the x-axis. I do not care if this needs a separate library or to simply switch to doing it in excel. Just not sure how to do this visual representation of "x or more".

Edit to try to clarify. I was to vizualize the data in such a way that with an X axis numbered from 1-54 each column will include all data greater.

i.e. Column 1 plots all values 1-54. Column 2 plots all values 2-54. Columns 3 plots all values 3-54. And so on.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is, but probably can be solved using the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) library

Comment: Will look into it, already use it in places but didnt see the option. To try to re-state the question I want to compound the x-axis. So the first col "1+" will include all values from 1-54. Then the next column "2+" will include all values from 2-54. And so on through to 54.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary that it is a capability of which ever graphing library you use.  Simply calculate your **y** values before graphing.  For example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.linspace(1,54,54), "y_pre":np.random.uniform(1,5,54)})
df["y"] = df["y_pre"].cumsum().sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

go.Figure([go.Bar(x=df["x"], y=df["y"], name="required"), go.Scatter(x=df["x"],y=df["y_pre"], name="inputs")])
```

[image]